# Calculating mean of normal distribution

Tags: mean, normalization, normal-distribution

How can I calculate the mean of normal distribution knowing the sd, a percentile and its value ?
I've got a question where the :
sd = 100
the 18 percentile's value is 1200
I standardized the distribution converting it to the Z score and using fi function and Z table.
then tried to calculate by P(Z > ((1200-mean)/100)) = 0.18
I got that mean = 1142.858 but it is a wrong answer.
what did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two different solutions of this question which are depends on the how the percentile is selected.

If we assume data are arranged in ascending order and pick the 1200 as initial 18 percentile value, the appropriate probabilty function would be P(z<((1200-mean)/100)) = 0.18 and then, if we apply the InvNorm function (Inverse Normal Probability Distribution Function), the corresponding z-score for a probability will be -0.915 which will make the equation as follows;
P(z<-0.915)=0.18 ->  -0.915 = (1200-mean)/100 -> the mean will be 1291.5

[image: #the graph of this situation can be seen from this link.]

If we assume data are arranged in ascending order and pick the 1200 as last 18 percentile value,the appropriate probabilty function would be P(z>((1200-mean)/100)) = 0.18 and then, if we apply the InvNorm function (Inverse Normal Probability Distribution Function), the corresponding z-score for a probability will be 0.915 which will make the equation as follows;
P(z> 0.915)=0.18 ->  0.915 = (1200-mean)/100 -> the mean will be 1108.5

[image: #the graph of this situation can be seen from this link.]